# WildFly 9 application server deployment errors on Intellij IDEA 14

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, wildfly

When I am creating a web project deploy on WildFly application server, I'm getting following errors.

Server logs:

```
2015-10-29 14:23:20,060 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."JavaEEFirstProject.war".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."JavaEEFirstProject.war".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "JavaEEFirstProject.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:163)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0160: Failed to mount deployment content
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.DeploymentRootMountProcessor.deploy(DeploymentRootMountProcessor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:156)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\mert\IdeaProjects\JavaEEFirstProject\out\artifacts\JavaEEFirstProject\JavaEEFirstProject.war (Sistem belirtilen yolu bulamıyor)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at org.jboss.vfs.spi.RootFileSystem.openInputStream(RootFileSystem.java:51)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VirtualFile.openStream(VirtualFile.java:254)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZipExpanded(VFS.java:533)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentMountProvider$Factory$ServerDeploymentRepositoryImpl.mountDeploymentContent(DeploymentMountProvider.java:108)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.DeploymentRootMountProcessor.deploy(DeploymentRootMountProcessor.java:91)
    ... 6 more
2015-10-29 14:23:20,066 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "JavaEEFirstProject.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"JavaEEFirstProject.war\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"JavaEEFirstProject.war\".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"JavaEEFirstProject.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0160: Failed to mount deployment content
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\Users\\mert\\IdeaProjects\\JavaEEFirstProject\\out\\artifacts\\JavaEEFirstProject\\JavaEEFirstProject.war (Sistem belirtilen yolu bulamıyor)"}}
2015-10-29 14:23:20,069 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "JavaEEFirstProject.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"JavaEEFirstProject.war\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"JavaEEFirstProject.war\".STRUCTURE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"JavaEEFirstProject.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYSRV0160: Failed to mount deployment content
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\\Users\\mert\\IdeaProjects\\JavaEEFirstProject\\out\\artifacts\\JavaEEFirstProject\\JavaEEFirstProject.war (Sistem belirtilen yolu bulamıyor)"}}
2015-10-29 14:23:20,078 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment JavaEEFirstProject.war (runtime-name: JavaEEFirstProject.war) in 7ms
2015-10-29 14:23:20,080 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (management-handler-thread - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."JavaEEFirstProject.war".STRUCTURE
```

On Intellij IDEA 14 has artifacts for deployed files. And I think I have a problem on this artifacts section because i am getting artifacts path errors with FileNotFoundException named. I am sharing artifacts print on following.

[image]

How can I add .war file with artifacts pages?

Answer (score 0):

Call "Build > Build Artifacts" and make sure (via Windows Explorer for example) that in the the JavaEEFirstProject folder there is a file called  "JavaEEFirstProject.war". Then redeploy it from IDEA.

Comment: i tried but it is not successfull. I am getting deployment source JavaEEFirstProject.war is not valid error